# needs guidance on distributing data on multiple GPUs

Tags: cuda, machine-learning, gpu, multi-gpu

I'm currently developing a machine learning toolkit for GPU clusters.
I tested logistic regression classifier on multiple GPUs.

I'm using a Master-Worker approach , where a master CPU creates several POSIX threads and matrices are divided among GPUs.

But the problem I have is how to store large matrices which can't be stored on a single machine. Are there any libraries or approaches to share data among nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how big are your matrices but you should check CUDA 4.0 that was released a couple of weeks ago. One of the main features is shared memory across multiple CUDA devices/GPUs